# How to manipulate rows in a grid correctly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following `GridView`

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhv6T.png)

I have the following problem if I edit a row already existent on the `grid` and add it again, it does not keep the sequence number to which it belonged and repeats the sequence number of the last row added.

What I need it to do: Once you edit the line and add it again keep the original sequence.

Obs. Inclusion of new lines (sequences) is already dynamic only need to correct the editing of lines already existing in the grid

**Example:**

I edited and added the first item again. And he did not keep the original sequence number (1) and still repeated the last sequence added.

[Grid edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZsA8.png)

Codes:

Add line:

```
 function AdicionarLinha(faixa, vlrInicial, vlrFinal, vlrBonus) {
    faixa = 1;
    var dados = new Array();
    j = 0;
    var repetido = false;
    $("#<%=gridFxValor.ClientID%> tr").each(function () {
        if (($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text()).trim().length > 0 || !($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text()).trim() == undefined && $(this).find('th:eq(2)').text().length <= 0) {
            if ($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text() == faixa && $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text() == vlrInicial && $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text() == vlrFinal && $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text() == vlrBonus) {
                $("#<%=txtFxCodigo.ClientID%>").val('');
                $("#<%=txtFxVlrInicial.ClientID%>").val('');
                $("#<%=txtFxVlrFinal.ClientID%>").val('');
                $("#<%=txtFxVlrBonus.ClientID%>").val('');
                criarDivAlert("Alerta", "Faixa de valor já inserida.");
                exibirAlerta(false);
                repetido = true;
            }               
            faixa++;
        }
    });
    if (repetido == false) {
        $("#<%=gridFxValor.ClientID%> tr").each(function () {
            if (($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text()).trim().length > 0 || !($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text()).trim() == undefined && $(this).find('th:eq(2)').text().length <= 0) {
                var linha = Array();
                i = 2;
                $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() != '') {
                        linha[i - 2] = ($(this).text()).trim();
                        i++;
                    }
                });
                $(this).remove();
                dados[j++] = linha;
            }
        });
        dados[dados.length] = new Array(faixa, vlrInicial, vlrFinal, vlrBonus);
        SetarDadosGrid(dados);
    }
}
```

Set grid data:

```
function SetarDadosGrid(dados) {
    $("#<%=gridFxValor.ClientID%>").append("");
    $("#<%=hdfTable.ClientID%>").val('');
    LimparGrid();
    var hidden = "";
    for (i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
        var string = "";
        string += "<tr id='tr" + i + "' style='color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;'>";
        string += "<td align='center'>";
        string += "<input type='image' name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridFaixa$ctl02$btnExcluirBonusValor' id='d" + i + "' onclick='javascript: DeletarLinha(this.id);' title='Excluir' text='Delete' src='../images/svg/delete.svg' style='width:15px;border-width:0px;'>";
        string += "</td><td align='center'>";
        string += "<input type='image' name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridFaixa$ctl02$btnEditarBonusValor' id='e" + i + "' onclick='EditartarLinha(this.id);' title='Editar' text='Editar' src='../images/svg/edit.svg' style='width:15px;border-width:0px;'></td>";
        for (k = 0; k < dados[i].length; k++) {
            string += "<td>";
            string += "<span>" + dados[i][k] + "</span>";
            string += "</td>";

        }


        hidden += Array(dados[i][0] + "$" + dados[i][1] + "$" + dados[i][2] + "$" + dados[i][3] + "|");
        string += "</tr>";
        $("#<%=gridFxValor.ClientID%>").append(string);
    }


    $("#<%=hdfTable.ClientID%>").val(hidden);
    $("#fxOferta").show();
    $("#<%=txtFxCodigo.ClientID%>").val('');
    $("#<%=txtFxVlrInicial.ClientID%>").val('');
    $("#<%=txtFxVlrFinal.ClientID%>").val('');
    $("#<%=txtFxVlrBonus.ClientID%>").val('');
}
```

Edit row:

```
function EditartarLinha(id) {
    var tr = document.getElementById("tr" + id.trim().replace('e', ''));
    $("#<%=txtFxCodigo.ClientID%>").val($(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text());
    $("#<%=txtFxVlrInicial.ClientID%>").val($(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text());
    $("#<%=txtFxVlrFinal.ClientID%>").val($(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text());
    $("#<%=txtFxVlrBonus.ClientID%>").val($(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text());
    tr.remove();
    AtualizaHidden();
```

Comment: Changes made to the DOM will not persist across a PostBack. If you want those changes saved you need to send them to the server in a Hidden Field, Ajax request etc.

Comment: @VDWWD 
I tried. But it did not work. Could you please illustrate how you would do this if you had this problem, please?

Comment: It's too broad to explain in a simple answer. But if you do not have knowledge of apis and ajax requests i suggest you abandon this and start using the RowEdit functionality of apsnet. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.